# How do I find out the domain name provider from our company?

Tags: server, dns, azure-web-app-service, hosting, google-cloud-dns

I want to verify domain ownership via DNS record like this :

[image]

There said to sign in to the domain name provider. I am confused how to sign in to the domain name provider. So I get some reference and the reference says to use https://www.whoishostingthis.com/

I check our domain and I get like this :

[image]

Is the domain name provider cloudflare? Do I have to log in to cloudflare?

But my colleague said that our website uses the portal azure

Which is true? Login to cloudflare or login to portal azure? I want to copy the TXT record into the DNS configuration

Answer (score 0):

All your domain's DNS records (including TXT record) are stored in its DNS zone. Where its active DNS zone is located is determined by the domain's name servers. In turn, a domain's name servers are set with the domain's registrar.

Based on your screenshot you provided, your Nameservers (NS) are pointing to CloudFlare, so this means you would need to add your TXT record there.

Here is the article for adding a TXT record: https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/verify-domain-txt

Comment: Can I add txt records to the portal azure? Our website is stored on the portal azure. I do not have access to cloudflare

Comment: Because you changed the NS to CloudFlare, your DNS records will be hosted in CloudFlare. Making any changed in Azure will not be reflected anywhere. On the internet, everyone will reach CloudFlare (NS) to query for your DNS records.